# OpenCV3のHDR合成機能について

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

OpenCV3.0にあるHDR合成をiOSより利用と思い下記のサイトを参考にコーディングしました。

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db7/tutorial_hdr_imaging.html

コードは下記の通りです。

```
- (UIImage *)testHDR
{
    cv::Mat images;
    cv::Mat1f times;
    //ここに画像を詰める
    cv::Mat srcMat1 = [self cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HDR1.JPG"]];
    cv::Mat srcMat2 = [self cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HDR2.JPG"]];
    cv::Mat srcMat3 = [self cvMatFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HDR3.JPG"]];
    images.push_back(srcMat1);
    images.push_back(srcMat2);
    images.push_back(srcMat3);
    //露光時間設定
    times.push_back(1/40);
    times.push_back(1/60);
    times.push_back(1/100);

    cv::Mat response;
    cv::Ptr<cv::CalibrateDebevec> calibrate = cv::createCalibrateDebevec();
    calibrate->process(images, response, times);

    cv::Mat hdr;
    cv::Ptr<cv::MergeDebevec> merge_debevec = cv::createMergeDebevec();
    merge_debevec->process(images, hdr, times, response);

    cv::Mat ldr;
    cv::Ptr<cv::TonemapDurand> tonemap = cv::createTonemapDurand();
    tonemap->process(hdr, ldr);

    cv::Mat fusion;
    cv::Ptr<cv::MergeMertens> merge_mertens = cv::createMergeMertens();
    merge_mertens->process(images, fusion);

    return [self UIImageFromCVMat:hdr];
}
```

そこで実際に動作させると`calibrate->process(images, response, times);`
で落ちてしまいます。多分、imagesとtimesの画像と露光時間の値のセット仕方がよくないだと思うのですが、参考となるソースコードがなくて困っています。

どなたかアドバイスお願い致します。

追記
下記のようなエラーが出力されます。

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (images.size() == times.total()) in process, file /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/photo/src/calibrate.cpp, line 70
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/photo/src/calibrate.cpp:70: error: (-215) images.size() == times.total() in function process
```

Answer (score 1):

参考サイトのコードでは`times.push_back(int/float)`になっていて、提示のコードは`times.push_back(int/int)`になっているような気がします。

2015-07-27 追記
また、imagesとtimesのそれぞれの変数の型が、参考サイトではそれらがstd::vectorとなっていてそのvectorの要素の型がcv::Matとfloatとなっています。
OpenCV内のassertに引っかかっているのはこちらが原因かもしれません。

Comment: 直してみたのですが、やっぱりダメでした。  
下記のようなエラーが出力されてしまいます・・・。  
  
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (images.size() == times.total()) in process, file /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/photo/src/calibrate.cpp, line 70  
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/precommit_ios/opencv/modules/photo/src/calibrate.cpp:70: error: (-215) images.size() == times.total() in function process`